# how to use slideNext/ slidePrev in react elastic caroussel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, react-elastic-carousel

I'm using react-elastic-caroussel in my project and i want to change the position of the arrows in such way that i wouldn't be able to do it only but changing the css, i'd have to change the html as well, since i don't know how to do that, i thought of using the slideNext and slidePrev method described here in it's documentation (https://sag1v.github.io/react-elastic-carousel/slideNext) so that i can just create my own buttons. The problem is, i have a functional component ad the example is using class components, i'm not very experienced with react and therefore i need help to adapt it to my code. Here's what i have so far.

```
<div className={Styles.tiposDeMaquinaContent}>
    <Carousel isRTL={false} breakPoints={breakPoints}>
         <CarouselItem imageUrl={EscavadeiraImg}>item 1</CarouselItem>
         <CarouselItem imageUrl={ManipuladorTelescopicoImg}>item 2</CarouselItem>
         <CarouselItem imageUrl={MinicarregadeiraImg}>item 3</CarouselItem>
         <CarouselItem imageUrl={MiniescavadeiraImg}>item 4</CarouselItem>
         <CarouselItem imageUrl={RetroescavadeiraImg}>item 5</CarouselItem>
         <CarouselItem imageUrl={PaCarregadeiraImg}>Pá carregadeira</CarouselItem>
    </Carousel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional component to implement it, this explanation might be useful:

[React-Elastic-Carousel Custom Arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566140/react-elastic-carousel-custom-arrow)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ref, using useRef().

Then pass the ref to the carousel component:

```
    const carouselRef = useRef(null)



    <Carousel
      renderPagination={() => <></>}
      breakPoints={breakPoints}
      itemPosition="CENTER"
      isRTL={false}
      showArrows={false}
      ref={carouselRef}
     >
```

Then you can use the function:

```
carouselRef.current.goTo(index)
```